# Passing parameters made easy in java

Tags: java, methods, parameters, jtextfield, jcomponent

```java
public class Model {


public void updateEvent(String name, Date date,String start, String venue, String details,
String opportunity, String more, String end, String row) {
//do stuff here

}


public class Controller {

 public void someMethod() {

 if(button==view.saveButton) {

 model.updateEvent(view.txtEventName.......);

 } }

}

public class View {
public JTextField txtEventName;
//10 more consisting of textarea, datechooser, etc


}
```

How can I pass a bunch of parameters to for `Controller` to pass to `Model` to update its state. Well, if the `View` is acting as form, it will have lots of text fields, text area etc. for data entry. rather than dealing with them individually how can controller gain access to all of them easily to pass to `model`. I dont want to simply keep adding `view.txtWhere.getText()` which is long.

Comment: Can you tidy up your code? It's all over the place!

Comment: Combine them with an object and pass by reference.

Comment: @RomanC can you show a sample demonstration or a link?

Comment: @MooHa I'd recommend you to do what Javadrien said. Additionally create a copy-constructor. Examples of copy-constructor see java tutorial on oracle site

Comment: @MooHa And [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/class/copy-constructor-example/)

Answer (score 1):

Create an "Event" class that has String name, Date date,String start, String venue, String details,
String opportunity, String more, String end, String row and use it instead ?